# Maximum value or bounds of a sequence based on its Z tranform

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, z-transform

Consider a sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ of real numbers and its Z tranform
$$A(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_iz^{-i}$$ We assume that all poles of $A(z)$ lie in the interior of the unit circle.  Thus, the inverse Z transform is defined by
$$a_i=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint{A(z)z^{i-1}dz}$$
where the contour of integration is the unit circle. I was wandering if it is possible to identify the $\sup_{0\leq i< \infty}|a_i|$ or some suitable bound based on the values of $A(z)$.